# Update mail merge source data from document

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to update the mail merge source data from Word?  For instance, if I set up a 'Version' field in my document, can I update it in word and have it propagate back to the data source?

If not using merge tags, is there an alternative way to complete this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word's MailMerge is really a read-only process, so there is no simple mechanism for doing what you suggest. (With some types of data source, it is sometimes possible to edit the data source via the User Interface using the Edit Recipients feature, but that is really almost like a standalone editor).

So if you need to be able to do this, what you typically have to do is use VBA (or whatever) to open and update the data source independently. How to do that depends on the data source - for example, opening and updating a Word data source would require Word Automation (or direct manipulation of the .docx) whereas updating a SQL Server source would need ADO. You then also have to consider whether it is even possible to open and modify the data source while the MailMerge data source is open.

FInally, if you need to update each data source record as it is merged, you would consider using VBA the MailMerge events in Word's object model. (Not available on Mac Word!)