# How can I update the data in an excel sheet so that it goes through to a word document mail merge

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I am trying to use 'mailings' in word to merge data from an excel sheet to make up number of documents and print them as PDFs, one document for each row of the excel sheet.

So far it is working ok, but I am struggling with updating the data in the Excel sheet. The only way I can see to update the mail merge documents with new data is to update the Excel Sheet, then save it with a new name, then link the word document to the new Excel file...

... is there an easier way of doing this?

I am working on a mac, using version 16.59 of Word for Mac, copyrighted 2022... any suggestions very gratefully received.

(Oh and I tried to see if this was asked before and [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/706064/update-mail-merge-source-data-from-document) seems similar, but I think it is different and I certainly don't understand the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Update the data in Excel, with the Word document closed.
2. Open the primary merge document.
3. Connect it to the Excel data as the source.
4. Perform the merge.

If a merge is to a new document, that is no longer a live merge document but rather an ordinary document.

See [Mailmerge using an Excel Spreadsheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3) (Microsoft support).

Comment: Many thanks for the answer,, will have to try that